# how to get the dsf code below to work?

Tags: windows, vb.net, vbscript, wdk

I wish to send input to multiple emulated mice using dsf(device simulation framework) incuded in the current windows ddk. My code is below the problem is device manager recogizes the device got added but my program (mouse mischief - also microsoft) doesnt create the addtional pointer like its supposed to:

```
WriteLine "Create first input report to send to the consumer control"
Dim strMessage 
strMessage = "Press Enter key to stop looping"
WriteLine strMessage
Do While NOT WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfLine
Dim InputReport1(4)
InputReport1(0) = CByte(0)
InputReport1(1) = CByte(100)
InputReport1(2) = CByte(100)
InputReport1(3) = CByte(0)
InputReport1(4) = CByte(0)

'PromptAndWaitForEnterKey "Queue input reports for processing"
GenericHIDDev.QueueInputReport(InputReport1), 10


'PromptAndWaitForEnterKey "Wait for the device to finish enumerating. Press enter to start processing input reports."
GenericHIDDev.StartProcessing
'WriteLine "You may send additional input reports at this time..."
'PromptAndWaitForEnterKey "Press enter at any time to stop processing input reports and start cleanup."
GenericHIDDev.StopProcessing
Input = WScript.StdIn.Read(1)
Loop
```

Note: this is the only section i modified of the TestGenericHid sample included with the dsf in the windows ddk(device driver kit). After install of windows ddk go to c:\Program Files\dsf\GenericHid or something similar to access the vbscript file.

Need mousmischief and windows ddk to fully understand whats going on and to correctly answer this. Dont worry all samples are in vbscript and can be redone in vb.net but i dont wish to waste time converting until i get the vbscript to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have since I posted this got it working with multiple mouse and within 2-3 months time will have a nice beta upload of my whole kinectmultipoint project here:
http://kinectmultipoint.codeplex.com

The code above is in a zip file at the address above in the preceding sentence.